# Regular expression that only matches before space or no space

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to make global regular expression that matches every capitalised letter after ! but only before a space or no space, no lowercase letters.

For example:

!ABC `<space>` !XYZ `<no space>` should return: ABC XYZ

but !ABCtext `<space>`!XYZ`<no space>` should only return: XYZ

The code I have so far is:

```
const regex = /![A-Z]*\s/g;
```

Which returns capital letters after ! even if they are directly followed by more text, without a space.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `![A-Z]+(?=[^\w]|$)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/VBKsT9/2)

Comment: Thanks a lot :) Solved

Comment: @pjproudhon yes this ok , but if word was end line not work

Comment: It does, as EOL is not a lowercase character. Works also without any lookaround if you rely on word boundary instead [https://regex101.com/r/VBKsT9/5].

Answer (score 0):

As @PJProudhon suggested, I think you could use [`!([A-Z]+)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/gOmteN/1) using a word boundary `\b`

`([A-Z]+)` will capture the capitalised letters after the `!` in group 1.

```
const regex = /!([A-Z]+)\b/g;
```